# How to Center the Pivot Point of a Model in SceneKit Editor

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

Is there anyway to center the pivot of a model? Currently (by default) it is set to the bottom left. I want to set to the center. How can I do that?

Here is the image:

[image]

**UPDATE**: I added another node and added the chair as a child.

So, now it works better but it does not rotate all the way and it resets the position if I continue to rotate. Here is the code for the panned operation:

```
  @objc func panned(recognizer :UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        var newAngleY :Float = 0.0

        if recognizer.state == .changed {

            let sceneView = recognizer.view as! ARSCNView
            let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: sceneView)

            print(translation.x)

            let scnHitTestResults = self.sceneView.hitTest(touchPoint, options: nil)

            if let hitTestResult = scnHitTestResults.first {

                if let parentNode = hitTestResult.node.parent {

                    newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(Double.pi)/180
                    newAngleY += currentAngleY
                    parentNode.eulerAngles.y = newAngleY
                }

            }
        }

        else if recognizer.state == .ended {
            currentAngleY = newAngleY
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change a pivot of the Chair using the `pivot`property of the SCNNode ([Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot))

You can change this using an `SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation` e.g:

```
nodeToAdd.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0,0,0)
```

This may solve the problem:

```
    //1. Get The Bounding Box Of The Node
    let minimum = float3(nodeToAdd.boundingBox.min)
    let maximum = float3(nodeToAdd.boundingBox.max)
    
    //2. Set The Translation To Be Half Way Between The Vector
    let translation = (maximum + minimum) * 0.5

    //3. Set The Pivot
    nodeToAdd.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
```

You could also change it within within a program like `Blender` or `Maya`.

Alternatively, and **probably much easier**, is to edit the model in the `SceneKit Editor` itself.

If you cant fix it's pivot, then what you can do is to create an `Empty Node`, and then add the Chair as a child of this, ensuring that it is centered within that.

This way you should be able to transform it's rotation for example more accurately.

Comment: Thanks! I used the last approach but for some reason the rotation was still buggy. And even though I was rotating the parentNode and not the chair Node it was still causing issues. Maybe it is an issue with the model itself.

Comment: I used your code above and it did not work as expected. The chair rotates but it is still rotating using the original coordinate system. I believe something is wrong with this model.

Comment: Updated the question with more progress.

Comment: Have you tried removing var newAngleY :Float = 0.0, and setting it here: var newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(Double.pi)/180

Comment: Thanks Josh! That was it :)

Comment: The correct way to calculate center of the bounding box is `(maximum + minimum) * 0.5`, not `(maximum - minimum) * 0.5`, I'll edit the answer. Basicaly, we don't need half of the interval, we need the position of the center between max and min.