# Setting Position and Scale of 3-D objects in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to make a simple application in which 3-D objects are placed in the scene through ARKit.

The application works perfectly when I build `SCNNode` objects through Objective-C code. However, when I try to place SCNNode objects loaded through a .obj file, the position and scale of the objects seems to be bizarre.

The way I create an SCNNode from a .obj file is as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"model" ofType:@"obj"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc] initWithURL:URL];
SCNNode *node = [asset objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now the problem is that when I set the node's transform to a feature point on a detected plane, the object is placed far above where it should be. Moreover its scale is absurdly large, through when viewed through model editing software, it is supposed to be only a few centimeters long/wide.

What am I missing? I'd appreciate any pointers towards understanding models (.objs specifically) better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - The scale of the objects being wrong is likely due to the fact that different 3D modelling software use different scaling units. The easy way to fix it is to just rescale the node in SceneKit:

```
yourNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5)
```

The more accurate option is to scale your model correctly in the 3D modelling software and export again.

2 - The reason your model is not being placed in the correct position is that the pivot point is not centred correctly. This can be done using your 3D modelling software or in Scenekit as explained in this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48979201/3975207